# Optimizing fleet size of buses based on certain constraints

Tags: r, optimization

**Objective:** To find the minimum number of buses required, number of chargers, total cost, and schedule of each bus.

**Problem Statement:**
Distance between two locations A and B is 14kms and it takes 40mins for one side journey(i.e only A to B). Bus service starts at 6:00 AM till midnight and every 10 mins a bus leaves from location A.

All buses are electric buses. There are two types; high capacity and low capacity. Both types have same passenger carrying capacity. High capacity bus have a range of 100kms for 100% battery whereas low capacity bus has a range of 60kms for 100% battery.

Chargers are of two types: Fast charger, Slow charger

Charging rates are as follows:

1. Fast charger for high capacity bus: 1.2kms/min
2. Fast charger for low capacity bus: 1.3kms/min
3. Slow charger for high capacity bus: 0.3kms/min
4. Slow charger for low capacity bus: 0.3kms/min

**Constraints:**

- Each bus is fully charged using slow charger to 100% at night.
- Fast charger cannot charge the battery above 70%.
- Consider 5 minute of overhead in case of charging because it will take total 5 minutes to plug & unplug a charger to a bus.
- Between two consecutive trips bus should be given 5-minute rest time. In case of charging, bus can be schedule to charge just after trip; and bus can leave just after charging.

**Cost:**

High capacity bus: 2crores (INR)

Low capacity bus: 1.3crores(INR)

Slow charger: 25lakhs (INR)

Fast charger: 60lakhs(INR)

I am required to find a minimum number of buses required considering

a) only high capacity bus

b) only low capacity bus

c) Mix. of both buses

---

I am new to optimization and I would like some help regarding how to approach and formulate this problem. I have read few articles about vehicle routing and scheduling problems but couldn't find much of help. I would like to solve this using R.

PS: I will highly appreciate any help on how to approach the problem rather than the complete solution.

Comment: Little response here, you could try at:  https://www.or-exchange.org/

Comment: Thanks for the link but I don't see any good response to other questions on that website. I have done some literature review and found out some interesting articles. If I get the solution to this problem I will definitely post the answer here.